# CURL with post data and create cookies

Tags: php, html, curl, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [curl authenticates but no web page is returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963373/curl-authenticates-but-no-web-page-is-returned)

I have made a code like this to get the return html data from the results of the curl, but I failed to do so. is there something wrong with my code?

My code :

```
<?php
/* STEP 1. let’s create a cookie file */
$ckfile = tempnam ("tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

/* STEP 2. visit the homepage to set the cookie properly */
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.batavia-air.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

/* STEP 3. visit cookiepage.php */
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.batavia-air.com/public/etiket/includes/class/booking/template/cariBookAjaxPros2.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

/* here you can do whatever you want with $output */
$datatopost = array (
            "ajax_type" => "non_ajax",
            "blnthnBerangkatPergi" => "12/12",
            "jmlInfant" => "0",
            "jmlPenumpang" => "1",
            "kalenderPergi" => "",
            "page" => "booking",
            "page" => "booking",
            "radio" => "flight",
            "ruteBerangkat" => "CGK",
            "ruteKembali" => "kembali",
            "ruteTujuan" => "AMQ",
            "tglBerangkatPergi" => "22",
);
  $ch = curl_init ($output);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
  echo $returndata;
  ?>
```

Or for the site does not need to use cookies?
Please help..Thanks

Comment: What does "you failed to do mean"? It is not returning anything? error? returns not what you expect?

Comment: I Have a blank page if i access my code...

Comment: Would have helped if the site was in English ... :)